# SImple Google Map Directions Link

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Ok I'm playing around with a link which once clicked I'd like it to divert the phone from the wepapp to google maps or an online version. each location of the will be different dependent on what the MySQL states so the coding will be something like this:

```
 <a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?hl={QTE.business_address},{QTE.business_postcode}" target="_blank" style="color:#999">
```

As you can see {QTE.business_address} Brings the address and {QTE.business_postcode} The Postcode, now what kind of link can I add to propogate these details onto a map in a mobile browser or even better Gmap App?

Comment: I think link handling in phone apps is handled by the phone. For example, if someone posts a link to a google map in an android app, when I click on the link in the app, the phone asks me if I want to complete the action using the browser or the native Maps app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You find here a (inofficial) description of the parameters: http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters

So the parameter has to be `q` instead of `hl`

Example: https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=Berlin,%20Alexanderplatz%201,10178